# Redirecionado do domínio

Tags: htaccess, http, redirecionamento, dns

Tenho um domínio pela Locaweb que redireciona para meu ip do vps via A e CNAME. Ele redireciona normal o link principalmente porém quando e digitado link com http:// sem o www e também mesmo se o http:// ele é redirecionado para o site principal diferente de acessar inserindo apenas o www.

No servidor está tudo ok porque meus testes usando o ip ao invés do domínio normalmente.

Redirecionam:
http://thiagopacheco.com/images/android.png
thiagopacheco.com/images/android.png

Funciona normalmente
http://www.thiagopacheco.com/images/android.png
www.thiagopacheco.com/images/android.png

Então pessoal como posso resolver?

via .htaccess ou na zona de DNS?

Comment: se está à direita de .com/ já não pode ser trabalhado a nível do dns
o dns não consegue lidar com mais do que com hostnames e domains dns

Answer (score 0):

O problema era no vps, para resolver.

> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Editar

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride none
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Para

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

> AllowOverride All

E depois habilitei o

> mod_rewrite

com o comando

> sudo a2enmod rewrite

Por fim um restart no apache.

> sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

E tudo ok, até os arquivos .htaccess que não funcionavam agora funcionam.